# Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Subscription': prototype, EMPTY

Tags: nativescript-angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { UIService } from "./shared/ui.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
```

//These are my imports

```
@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent, { static: false }) drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;

    enteredChallenge: string[] = [];
    private drawerSub = Subscription; //I have put subscription here
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    constructor (private uiService: UIService, private changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    onChallengeInput(enterText: string){
        this.enteredChallenge.push(enterText);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.drawerSub = this.uiService.drawerState.subscribe(
            () => {
                if(this.drawer){
                    this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer.toggleDrawerState();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){

        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        if(this.drawerSub){
            this.drawerSub.unsubscribe();
        }

    }
 }
```

I have 2 errors
1 -> Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'typeof Subscription'.
2 -> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Subscription': prototype, EMPTY

I have included Subscription and the stuff I need but I don't understand why I still get this error. Can someone help me out?

Comment: private drawerSub = new Subscription();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also made this simple mistake and couldn't spot the typo.
The line:

```
private drawerSub = Subscription;
```

Should be:

```
private drawerSub: Subscription;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move **private drawerSub = Subscription** from AppComponent class to the **constructor** class:

**Instead of this:**

```
private drawerSub = Subscription;
```

**Use This:**

```
constructor(private drawerSub:Subscription) {}
```

**now this will work:**

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.drawerSub){
        this.drawerSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help :)